# Distributing a library built with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm building a library that uses Spring 4.2.4 and am planning to bundle Spring with the library, to make a self sufficient jar with all dependencies included because some of my clients don't use Maven.

However, some of the clients using the library could be using a different version of Spring already in their applications, some as old as Spring 2.5. In this case, they would exclude the bundled version of Spring. Then how do I handle feature compatibility issues? For example, Spring 4 can have multiple PropertySources, and this is not supported in earlier versions.

Comment: Spring 2.5 is not compatible with Spring 4 as you already noted, so if they don't want to use Spring 4, then they can't use your library - unless you make a new version of your library that works with Spring 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you really need to, you can bundle the libraries you want in your library and alter their packages to make sure that no collision or class loader conflicts happens in scenarios such as what you describe happens. If Maven is your build system, you could use the [Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) to accomplish this. Such an approach is taken in such popular libraries as Jersey 2 where the guava library classes are included in the distribution with modified package name.

Comment: Ah. Will take that route then. Thanks!